# Python: how to read a url with ".data " suffix

Tags: python, pandas, url

I'm trying to read data from this url - "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/parkinsons/parkinsons.data" into a pandas dataframe.

I've used this technique:

```
 park_df = pd.read_html('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
 databases/parkinsons/parkinsons.data', header=0, flavor='bs4')
```

but I get an error as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-804373f977ab> in <module>()
----> 1 park_df = pd.read_html('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine- 
learning-databases/parkinsons/parkinsons.data', header=0, flavor='bs4')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in 
read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, 
parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, 
na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
    985                   decimal=decimal, converters=converters, 
na_values=na_values,
    986                   keep_default_na=keep_default_na,
--> 987                   displayed_only=displayed_only)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in 
_parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    813             break
    814     else:
--> 815         raise_with_traceback(retained)
    816 
    817     ret = []

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    402         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    403             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 404         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    405 else:
    406     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

ValueError: No tables found
```

Can you suggest what I'm doing wrong here, what else could be a better option. Please do open the url to check how the data looks, with the header in the 1st row (containing column names) and data following further below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) is used for convert html tables to pandas DataFrame, for convert csv format use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/parkinsons/parkinsons.data'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

print (df.head())

             name  MDVP:Fo(Hz)  MDVP:Fhi(Hz)  MDVP:Flo(Hz)  MDVP:Jitter(%)  \
0  phon_R01_S01_1      119.992       157.302        74.997         0.00784   
1  phon_R01_S01_2      122.400       148.650       113.819         0.00968   
2  phon_R01_S01_3      116.682       131.111       111.555         0.01050   
3  phon_R01_S01_4      116.676       137.871       111.366         0.00997   
4  phon_R01_S01_5      116.014       141.781       110.655         0.01284   

   MDVP:Jitter(Abs)  MDVP:RAP  MDVP:PPQ  Jitter:DDP  MDVP:Shimmer  ...  \
0           0.00007   0.00370   0.00554     0.01109       0.04374  ...   
1           0.00008   0.00465   0.00696     0.01394       0.06134  ...   
2           0.00009   0.00544   0.00781     0.01633       0.05233  ...   
3           0.00009   0.00502   0.00698     0.01505       0.05492  ...   
4           0.00011   0.00655   0.00908     0.01966       0.06425  ...   

   Shimmer:DDA      NHR     HNR  status      RPDE       DFA   spread1  \
0      0.06545  0.02211  21.033       1  0.414783  0.815285 -4.813031   
1      0.09403  0.01929  19.085       1  0.458359  0.819521 -4.075192   
2      0.08270  0.01309  20.651       1  0.429895  0.825288 -4.443179   
3      0.08771  0.01353  20.644       1  0.434969  0.819235 -4.117501   
4      0.10470  0.01767  19.649       1  0.417356  0.823484 -3.747787   

    spread2        D2       PPE  
0  0.266482  2.301442  0.284654  
1  0.335590  2.486855  0.368674  
2  0.311173  2.342259  0.332634  
3  0.334147  2.405554  0.368975  
4  0.234513  2.332180  0.410335  

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```